# UINavigation Controller Before Tab Bar Controller and After Tab Bar Controller?

Tags: ios, tabs, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller

I have an application which starts with `UINavigationController` and contains a `UITableViewController`. In the `UITableViewController` on an event `Tab Bar Controller` is pushed which contains 5 `View Controller` each with one `UINavigation Controller`.

The `NavigationController` inside the `Tab Bar` is coming beneath the `UINavigationController` which is before the Tab bar.

Hierarchy of the application:

```
UINavigationController >

  UITableViewController >

     Tab Bar >

        5 View Controllers each with UINavigationController >

             View Controllers inside each ViewController above
```

I want the respective UINavigationController , Should replace the above UINavigationController ..

Comment: what you actually want. i think you want, you have a UITableViewController and a tabbar controller on that class. so if you click one tabbar button you navigate to another class and in that class you don't want that tabbar. am i right ?

Comment: No its not like that I have explained the hierarchy above.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's HIG recommends that you use the TabBarController on App level, I wouldn't risk to abuse it like that.

> In general, use a tab bar to organize information at the app level. A tab bar is well suited for use in the main app view because it’s a good way to flatten your information hierarchy and provide access to several peer information categories or modes at one time.

https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH12-SW52